# Use "and" instead of ampersand, when using the natbib package and agsm-style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm a newbie to bibtex, therefore my question might be straightforward.
My problem is the following:
I need to cite in "Havard Style" and I want to use the agsm-style of the natbib package.
However, in the text of the document, I want to have an "and" instead of the ampersand in between two authors.

How to accomplish that?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={2.5cm},rmargin={2.5cm},
tmargin={2cm},bmargin = {2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for equations over multiple lines
\usepackage[hang,bottom]{footmisc} % Fußzeile bleibt am Boden %
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{longtable} % table over two pages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{filecontents}


\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} %note below table

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{natbib}  % havard style citation


\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother




\newtheorem{theorem}{Definition}[section]




\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.8em}



\usepackage{hyperref}
\linespread{1.25}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}


\newcommand\harvardand{\&}




\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Literatur2.bib}
@Article{craigim2010,
  Title                    = {Deploying Enterprise Solutions},
  Author                   = {Craigim WW and Craigim XX},
  Journal                  = {Journal of Force Multiplication and Utilization},
  Year                     = {2010},
}

@Article{craigim2009,
  Title                    = {Marketplace Leveraging},
  Author                   = {Craigim},
  Journal                  = {Journal of Human Assets},
  Year                     = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\section{Start}

Why is there always the ampersand between the authors when using \citet{craigim2010}

\bibliography{Literatur2}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to change `&` to `and` only inside the text, while keeping `&` in the bibliography, or do you want to change both appearences?

Comment: @leandis - thanks for your quick reply! I want to change both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to change both appearences (in the text and in the bibliography) should be adding

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\harvardand}{and}}
```

to your preamble. The `.bst` file uses the command `harvardand` to print `&` while the above command changes `\harvardand` to print `and` instead.

Comment: you made my day! Submission is today ;)